# How to show images in webview_flutter plugin?

Tags: android, image, https, webview, flutter

I have used the webview_flutter package to show a website (https://sprokkelbos.nl/collectie/) in my app. The page stays blank when using the https url. If using the http url the website is shown but without the images. The url is using https and the images are also with https (https://sprokkelbos.nl/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/HB1_3221.jpg).

When opening chrome in the simulation then the url is opening and the images are shown. Only inside the app in the webview it is not shown. I tried other packages in flutter but they all give the same result. The standard initial url used is flutter.io and this website is always working in the webview inside the app.

Is there a setting somewhere in the code of the app to allow the images to be shown? Is this an SSL issue? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have suspected, this has actually nothing to do with images, and nothing with flutter. It's just that your SSL server configuration is missing some intermediary certificates. Chrome itself seems to support your intermediaries, but android does not. See https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=sprokkelbos.nl

Check the installation documentation of your web server or certificate provider, or contact their support. You should be able to install a complete certificate chain to a trusted root certificate. E.g. for apache https://support.sectigo.com/Com_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA01N000000zFJb make sure you've got the `SSLCertificateChainFile` configured correctly. Or for nginx: https://support.sectigo.com/Com_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA01N000000zFJQ

Comment: Thank you! Have to contact the developer of the website how he/she set things up. Then I will search how to configure the SSLCertificateChainFile correctly in my project.